# Is NewRelic nrsysmond system agent open source or not?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am curious if NewRelic system agent is open source or not as in the end this is a piece of code that you would endup installing on your systems so you may want to see what it does to evaluate all risks.

While performing a google search on "nrsysmond source code" I got one link to their own discussions forums and when I tried to visit them, they forced me to create an account first, after this surprise:

**Sorry, you don't have access to that topic!**

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/is-sourcecode-of-nrsysmond-publicly-available/32933

Am I a little bit paranoid or I do also get the impression that there is a desire to keep some information private.

Answer (score 0):

NewRelic is a freemium company ,some code is open source as [nrsysmond](https://github.com/newrelic/puppet-nrsysmond)

> Puppet module to install the New Relic Server Monitor

see [license](https://github.com/newrelic/puppet-nrsysmond/blob/master/LICENSE)

> newrelic/puppet-nrsysmond is licensed under the
>
> MIT License

So you can search the code inside github.

I know that NewRelic support systen is full/partially available for paying support customers, and the link isn't available even for paying customer so discussion may have been removed/moved/hidden.